# std::allocator<_Ty>::deallocate : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'X' to 'Y'

Tags: c++

I'm upgrading some C++ code from VisualStudio 6 towards VisualStudio 2008.

There is a class "GenExportableTree" which looks a lot like xtree from Dinkumware http://www.dinkumware.com/xtree.txt

When compiling the library which contains this GenExportableTree, I get the following error:

```
Error   37  error C2664: 'std::allocator<_Ty>::deallocate' : cannot convert 
parameter 1 from 'std::CGenExportableTree<_K,_Ty,_Kfn,_Pr,_A>::_Node *' to 
'CCfwSchemaInfo *'
```

which are the following lines:

```
void _Freenode(_Nodeptr _S)
        {
            allocator.deallocate( _S, 1); 
        }
```

Some extra info:
The you can find the complete implementation of the GenExportableTree under the dinkumware link above.

Where the CCfwSchemaInfo comes around the corner I can find following declarations:

```
typedef CGenExportableMap<wstring, CCfwSchemaInfo, GenNoCaseWString> CfwSchemaTable;
```

The definition of the CGenExportableMap is as follows:

```
template<class _K, class _Ty, class _Pr = less<_K>,
    class _A = allocator<_Ty> >
    class CGenExportableMap {
public:
    typedef CGenExportableMap<_K, _Ty, _Pr, _A> _Myt;
    typedef pair<const _K, _Ty> value_type;
....
....

    typedef _K key_type;
    typedef _Ty referent_type;
    typedef _Pr key_compare;
    typedef _A allocator_type;
    typedef  typename _A::reference _Tref;
    typedef CGenExportableTree<_K, value_type, _Kfn, _Pr, _A> _Imp;
```

In this last line is where the GenExportableTree gets used in the GenExportableMap definition.

As this previously all compiled correctly under vs6, I guess actually everything is correct - probably the compiler is just more strictly now  - so where should I start looking to find the error the compiler is complaining about? And how should i resolve this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us enough details to be able to make useful guesses. What are all the types? What are their declarations or typedefs?

Comment: "As this previously all compiled correctly under vs6, I guess actually everything is correct" this is a non sequitur. Visual C++ 6.0 can _barely_ even be called C++. It's not that compilers are stricter now: it's that compilers are _C++ compilers_ now; VS6 was just so far removed from compliance that it's become a joke and a historical footnote at the same time.

Comment: @Kerrek: Ideally we'd have enough information that we would not have to guess at all!

Comment: @Tomalak: Haha, good point -- I was going for a "meet the OP half-way" thing... Now I stopped getting reputation for upvotes, so I'll switch off and get icecream.

Comment: @Kerrek: I added some extra info about where the classes are defined and used. Thanks for your remarks

Answer (score 2):

VC6 had **serious** template problems so it couldn't support allocators according to the standard. They used a couple of special hacks that have long since been removed.

If some code still depends on those non-standard interfaces, I think your only option is to fix the code so it works with the current (standard) allocator interface. Sorry.

Comment: All 100% true; still, I'm hesitant to vote this up since it doesn't really tell the OP how to fix it. He hasn't provided enough information for you to do so, but still ... you don't.

Comment: @Tomalak - I replied to the first part "so where should I start looking to find the error the compiler is complaining about?". I don't have a simple solution to the second question.

Comment: @Bo - which are these "non-standard interface", how can I check this? Can you gove me an example with the current (standard) allocator inteface?

Comment: @sfonck - I haven't used VC6 for a long time (since VS2003 came out :-), so this is mostly from memory. I believe your problem is that `deallocate` took a `void*` pointer in VC6, instead of a `T*` which `std::allocator<T>` is supposed to do. That way you could pass any type of pointer to any `std::allocator<T>`, which is what is happening here. Nowadays, we have to use a separate allocator for each type, which means that some current containers might store several allocators and use them as needed.

Comment: @Bo: do you know some type of open-source project where I can see this in use (and try to learn from it)?

Comment: @sfonck - I do closed software :-), so I don't know much about the open projects. However, the source for the std::allocator and the containers are all available in your compiler's include files. You could have a look there.